# ¿Como numerar resultados de consulta MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Como puedo numerar los resultados de una consulta en MySql?

Partiendo de que tenemos una tabla.

Tabla_A

```sql
Nombre Edad Departamento 
User1   33    BD 
User2   34    BD 
User3   25    BI 
User4   45    BI
```

Tabla_Resultado

```sql
Nombre Edad Departamento  Media_Dept  Ranking_empresa
User1   33     BD            33.5         3
User2   34     BD            33.5         2
User3   25     BI            35           4
User4   45     BI            35           1
```

La media de edad la obtengo con:

```sql
SELECT Departamento, ROUND(AVG(EDAD),2) as Media_Depart FROM tabla_a GROUP BY Departamento
```

pero no se como numerar los resultados y darle un ranking por edad

Gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: basado en opiniones, cuál es el criterio del ranking? nosotros te ayudamos con el c'odigo

Comment: Que versión de MySQL usas?

Comment: El ranking es del mas veterano al mas joven, siendo el usuario4 el numero 1, y la version de mysql no se como verla, uso el Wamp y me muestra una version MySql 5.7.24

Comment: Si usarás la 8 existe una window function que lo hace por ti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea una variable e inicializala con 0 y luego crea una tabla para de ahí obtener el promedio por departamento y luego ponerlo con un `JOIN`

```
SET @ranking = 0;
SELECT
  nombre,
  edad,
  tabla_a.departamento,
  media_por_dep,
  @ranking := @ranking + 1 as ranking
FROM
  tabla_a
JOIN (
  SELECT
    departamento,
    ROUND(AVG(edad),2)  as media_por_dep
  FROM tabla_a
  GROUP BY departamento
) med ON med.departamento = tabla_a.departamento
ORDER BY
  edad DESC;
```

El resultado de esa consulta me devuelve:

```
nombre  edad  departamento  media_por_dep  ranking
user4    45        BI           35.00         1
user2    34        BD           33.50         2
user1    33        BD           33.50         3
user3    25        BI           35.00         4
```

Comment: Funciona correctamente, gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con este código:

```
set @row_num = 0; 
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index, Departamento, ROUND(AVG(EDAD),2) as Media_Depart FROM tabla_a GROUP BY Departamento;
```

Si lo que quieres es ordenar los resultados prueba con esto:

```
set @row_num = 0; 
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as Ranking, Departamento, ROUND(AVG(EDAD),2) as Media_Depart FROM tabla_a GROUP BY Departamento ORDER BY Ranking;
```

Comment: Gracias, estamos mas cerca, muestra un id por row pero no nos numera cual es el "ranking de edad" del mas veterano al mas joven de la empresa, intentare y publicare el resultado

Comment: Eso es lo que muestra el código o se pegó mal en el comentario? @hispasofttv

Comment: 1 User1 BD 33,50
2 User3 BI 35,00   perdona no se como editar para que se vea como tabla, pero el orden de los campos es row_index, nombre, departamento, Media_departamento

Comment: @hispasofttv Prueba con el nuevo código que puse en la publicación.

Comment: Gracias, he probado y añadido el campo nombre para que se vaya pareciendo a los que se solicita, estamos mas cerca pero no ordena por el mas veterano, en este caso por el usuario de 45 años, la consulta quedo asi:   ` set @row_num = 0; 
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as Ranking, nombre, Departamento, ROUND(AVG(EDAD),2) as Media_Depart FROM tabla_a GROUP BY nombre ORDER BY Ranking;`

Comment: He realizado un cambio, la consulta queda asi `set @row_num = 0; 
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as Ranking, nombre, Departamento, edad, ROUND(AVG(EDAD),2) as Media_Depart FROM tabla_a GROUP BY nombre ORDER BY edad;`  pero me "numera" por usuario siendo el 1 el usuario 1, y asi sucesivamente el usuario 4 es el ranking 4